# Verilog: looping instances in hierarchical path

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Here's the snippet of the code: 
I am trying to load a text file (256 lines with 32 binary values) in register. But my registers are designed hierarchically. So i am trying to to do the following loop:

```
 reg [31:0] data [ 0:255];   
initial $readmemb("vectors.txt", data);
generate
      for ( j=0;j<32;j=j+1) begin: BLOCK
         assign  ITR_MAC_AF.IAF.IREG3_31_.IREG2_7_.IREG[j]=data[0];     
      end
   endgenerate
```

But it doesn't like looping through instances. Is there any fixes for this?
I have 32 IREG_3 instances, each IREG3 has 8 IREG2 and each IREG has 32 latches inside them.

thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you are looking for if there was no `generate` statement? i.e. if you had to manually expand it out.

Comment: If i wanted do it in matlab i would probably did something like this. Does this make sense?                                                                                                                       
 reg [31:0] data [ 0:255];

initial $readmemb("vectors.txt", data);

for ( j=0;j<32;j=j+1)begin
   for ( j=0;j<8;j=j+1)begin
       for ( k=0;k<256;k=k+1)begin
 ITR_MAC_AF.IAF.IREG3[i].IREG2[j].IREG[31:0] = data[k];  
   end
end

Comment: Basically i have a hierarchy of 32*8*32 registers and i want to load 32 bits of data in the lower 32 register outputs.

Comment: how exactly did you create your instances? what is IREG? can you show the code?

Comment: i made the design as schematic then netlisted it for verilog. IREG are basically flip flop latches for scanning data.

Comment: how exactly did you instantiate them in verilog?

Answer (score 0):

If the netlist created names like `IREG3_0_`, `IREG3_1_`, ...`IREG3_31_`, there is no way to create looping statements that access the _ *NNN* _ part. You might as well used `IREG3_dog_`, `IREG3_milk_`, ... to name your indices.

You need to get your netlister to preserve the array of instances so you can access as a nested for loop. Or you may need to write the netlist manually.

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you can implement something like that using generate blocks. Though it will look a bit different from what you have. Generate blocks create block names which contain indexing in them which could be referenced from other generate blocks.

The following example hierarchically instantiates regA and regB. the latter contains variable REG. The code below initializes REG in a hierarchical manner (using `initial`  block). Initialization and top instantiation is done in module `top`. you can compile it and see the results.

BTW, if you compile in system verilog mode, you can get rid of `generate/endgenerate` keywords and use `i++` syntax.

```
module top();
  regTOP regTOP();

  genvar i, j, k;

  generate
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) begin
      for (j = 0; j < 3; j = j + 1) begin
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k = k + 1) begin
          initial regTOP.R[i].regA.R[j].regB.REG[k] = (i << 4) | (j << 2) | k;
        end
      end
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule

module regA();
  genvar i;
  generate
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) begin: R
      regB regB();
    end
  endgenerate

endmodule

module regB();
  integer i;
  reg[6:0] REG[3:0];

  always @*
    for (i=0; i < 3; i = i + 1)
      $display("%m: reg[%0d]=%0d", i, REG[i]);
endmodule

module regTOP();
  genvar i;
  generate
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i = i + 1) begin: R
      regA regA();
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```